# How to select input options for a function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that acts as an autocorrect. So basically somewhere in the script a user will assign a colour to a variable and then the function checks whether it is part of a list of common spelling errors for that colour and then assign the correct spelling.

```
autocorrect = function(variable = variable) {
if (variable %in% c("grren",
                  "geen",
                  "freen",
                  "grees",
                  "grean",
                  "geren",
                  "gren",
                  "breen",
                  "gree",
                  "greeny",
                  "genn",
                  "greeen",
                  "grenn",
                  "greena",
                  "dreen",
                  "greent",
                  "greeg",
                  "greetn",
                  "greem",
                  "tgreen",
                  "greenly",
                  "agreen",
                  "grene",
                  "treen",
                  "greean",
                  "greesn",
                  "3green",
                  "reen",
                  "greeno",
                  "greeb",
                  "grrens")) {

variable <- "green"
  }
}
```

Then a user would assign a colour:

```
colour <- "grene"
```

Which is spelled incorrectly. The function will then reassign the colour to the correct spelling:

```
colour
"green"
```

How do I get the function to use various variable names as input? For example if I have:

```
colour1 <- "grene"
colour2 <- "grean"
```

Then use it something like:

```
autocorrect(colour1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything at the moment, but in any case try to vectorize it, i.e. `autocorrect <- Vectorize(autocorrect); autocorrect(c('grean', 'greeg'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `return` value to the function, to return either the corrected colour or, if the colour does not match, some other return value. The parameter should also be called something more meaningful than `variable`, such as `str` (for string). Here is a revised function:

```
autocorrect = function(str) {
  if (str %in% c("grren",
                      "geen",
                      "freen",
                      "grees",
                      "grean",
                      "geren",
                      "gren",
                      "breen",
                      "gree",
                      "greeny",
                      "genn",
                      "greeen",
                      "grenn",
                      "greena",
                      "dreen",
                      "greent",
                      "greeg",
                      "greetn",
                      "greem",
                      "tgreen",
                      "greenly",
                      "agreen",
                      "grene",
                      "treen",
                      "greean",
                      "greesn",
                      "3green",
                      "reen",
                      "greeno",
                      "greeb",
                      "grrens")) {

    return("green")
  } else {
    return(str)
  }
}
```

This takes the string as a parameter and returns the corrected value, or the original string if it is not found in the autocorrect list. You could also consider returning `NA` or similar if no match is made.

**Some sample output:**

```
> autocorrect("grene")
[1] "green"
> autocorrect("banana")
[1] "banana"
> colour1 <- "grene"
> colour2 <- "grean"
> autocorrect(colour1)
[1] "green"
> autocorrect(colour2)
[1] "green"
>
```

Comment: It works, but it does not reassign str. Is there a way that str will now be reassigned as if: str <- "green"

Comment: Generally, a function does not "reassign" a value, it "returns" a value. So if you had something like `oldColour <- "grene"` you could say `newColour <- autocorrect(oldColour)`. This would then assign "green" to `newColour`. You could of course also say `oldColour <- autocorrect(oldColour)` - that is perfectly valid and would assign the autocorrected value back to the variable `oldColour`. Does this cover what you want to do?

Comment: Yesss!! Thank you so much, it's actually obvious now that you mention it!

Comment: Also, the variable `str` is local to the function and is not available outside the scope of the function.